# Regular expression does not work in EMEditor

Tags: regex, regular-expressions, search-and-replace

I have a simple Regular expression to select all text between X-Mozilla-Status and [Chat Info]. I tried it at https://regexr.com/, and it all works great. However, it can't find anything if I add it to the find area in EMEditor and search my files.

I am using:

X-Mozilla-Status([\s\S]*?)[Chat Info]

the text it suppose to select is as following

X-Mozilla-Status: 0000
X-Mozilla-Status2: 00000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:
X-Account-Key: account2

------=_NextPart_000_0790_B78A7E3E.3A9C4181
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[Chat Info]

Message .....

It works perfectly in regex.com but not in EMEditor regex search.

Is there an alternative, or do I have an error?

Thank you, everyone, for the guidance.

Best wishes,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this for a while, I decided to try another editor.
This resolved my issue using Notepad++ did the job perfectly.

Thanks everyone to look at my issue